# Web Scraping html input tags that are hidden

Tags: c#, web-scraping

I am using c# winforms and the WebBrowser Control from the toolbox to routinely navigate to a url and scrape its data. I have binded the event webbrowser_documentcomplete event and once in the event I am using the line

```
 HtmlElement element= WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("MainRadGrid_ClientState");
```

to get the element. Once I have the HtmlElement I was able to use the OuterText property to see what is in the element as so

```
element.OuterText.Trim()
```

My issue is that the code above was working even when the input type that I was looking at was set to 'hidden'. Things seem to have changed at this point and I am no longer able to get the outertext value. Can someone help me be able to get the outertext of the element or just get into the hidden element to gets its data

```
<input id="MainRadGrid_ClientState" name="MainRadGrid_ClientState" type="hidden" /> </div>
```

Comment: This is far too broad of a question for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

There might be difficulty depending on how tricky the page author was.

Input type='hidden' is one thing, but there might be other fields that are visually hidden with a CSS style or simply positioned off the screen. Finally, there may be values that are composed at the last second as the page is submitted, so you have to think deep about what values you want. Additionally, some fields may be opened, generated, or removed after a page is loaded, defeating simple fetch-the-page scraping.

But in the case of input tags of type hidden, an XSLT search can get you a list of those nodes pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how exactly you're scraping, but in general the answer to your question should be a resounding "YES."  If you're scraping web content that means you're downloading the same content (HTML source, etc) that would get sent to any browser by the web server.  In your scraper, you don't need to honor "hidden" styles or anything of the sort. To your code, it's just a really big string or a series of strings.  You can parse them however you see fit.

Comment: I have created a web scraper using c#  and using WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("") to get the element. Once I Get the element I was looking at the HtmlElement Outertext and I saw what was in the grid being displayed. All of sudden things have changed and Im no longer able to get anything in the Outertext. Any advice